Where to put packages folders with source you want always available to ROS2?
Historically I always did apt install ros-humble-<package_name> but for some reason the package I am wanting is not available.
I can download the package from github and compile it using colcon but I'm having issues using its messages in other packages(can't find source file) and in general I don't want to source it every time.
How do I install the package with the folder like I would using apt install?

May I ask which is the problem of sourcing it every time? You could just create a workspace with only that package and set it up into the bashrc in order to just source that package.

what's the package you want to install? if it's not an "official" Ros package it won't be available through apt. You'll have to compile it manually. As @ÁngeLoGa suggested, you can the source command in your bashrc.

But where do I put it? Where do apt-get packages get installed?

You should consider not mixing packages installed with apt, and others that weren't installed that way. Normally, you would use apt for packages that you won't be modifying and just want to call them. If you are planning to make modifications or develop anything, a better sugestion is to create a workspace in your root directory and installing the package on it, and source it each time you start a terminal. This can be done automatically as @Suchetan suggested editing the bashrc. apt-get are installed in the main install of ros /opt/ros/<version>/

If you don't want to go through the manual process of sourcing the workspace everytime, you could consider adding it to your .bashrc or your .zshrc.
It would look something like this.
echo "source ~/your_ws/install/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
